# How to use Rcpp with TDM-gcc 4.8.1?

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm using R 3.0.2 under Windows 7 (32bit) and has TDM-GCC-32 (gcc (tdm-2) 4.8.1) in the path.

When I try to use cppFunction, I get some error:

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)
src <- '
SEXP hellofun(){
 std::vector<std::string> s;
  s.push_back("hello");
s.push_back("world");
return Rcpp::wrap(s);
}'
hello_fun <- cppFunction(src)
```

Error message:

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) (from file1c8c8c929f5.cpp.R#1) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/ssss11/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeywSmo/sourcecpp_1c8c47543253/sourceCpp_60750.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  Invalid access to memory location
```

However when I run example(cfuntion), it succeeds.

```
library(inline)
example(cfunction)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what `TDM-GCC-32 (gcc (tdm-2) 4.8.1)` may be -- but our documentation repeatedly stresses that one and only one compiler is support on Windows:  the one that comes with the version of [Rtools](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) corresponding to your R version.

Now, 'TDM-gcc-32' may well be feature compatible, but if you want to use it you probably have to rebuild your *entire* R stack (ie R itself, all packages, ...) with it.

Sot it might be best to wait for R Core / CRAN to update Rtools to a version newer than gcc-4.6.*

Comment: That is interesting -- thanks for trying.  Maybe you could summarize your steps in a post to r-devel. There may well be other Windows users who would want to try a newer compiler.

Comment: @Shuguang I too have re-compiled Rcpp and its' dependiencies using a recent g++ (4.8.2 here).  How did you test and confirm exception handling was working as it should from within Rcpp sourced functions?

Comment: @Thell Sorry. I didn't make such deep test.