# Using a different gcc version from that included with Rtools with Rcpp on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, r, gcc, rcpp

Before I embark on updating gcc, has anyone actually attempted this, and can they confirm building R from source is required to update the gcc version one uses to compile c++ code with Rcpp (i.e. not necessarily for package authoring and certainly not for CRAN-valid packages)?

See Dirk's answer to this question, and the follow-on comment from the original poster [How to use gcc 4.8.1 with Rcpp on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21355022/how-to-use-rcpp-with-tdm-gcc-4-8-1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rebuilding `R` from source does not appear necessary. Here are the steps I used for a `Windows 7 x64` system, running `R 3.1.1` with `Rtools 3.1.0.1942`. The implications of this update to `gcc` have not been thoroughly tested:

1. Start a clean R session and `remove.packages("Rcpp")` and anything else `Rcpp` related. Close R session.
2. Download and run MinGW-builds from [Link to MinGW-builds installer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/mingw-builds-install/).
3. Select gcc version 4.8.1/Arch x64/Threads posix/Exception sjlj /Build rev 5 and install to [Drive]:\Rtools\mingw-builds\ ...
4. Update the system `PATH` variable to include these entries in the following order (at or near the top of `PATH`): `[Drive]:\R\R-3.1.1\bin\x64;[Drive]:\Rtools\bin;[Drive]:\Rtools\mingw-build\x64-4.8.1-posix-sjlj-rev5\mingw64\bin\;`
   the 3rd path entry **replaces** the one included by the `Rtools` installer: `[Drive]:\Rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin`
5. Restart, or otherwise, to reflect PATH changes.
6. Start a clean `R` session and run `install.packages("Rcpp")` and repeat for all the other packages that were removed in step 1.

These steps have been followed using `R 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)` with `Rcpp 0.11.2`. It is easiest to do this using `rgui.exe`, and not via an IDE such as `RStudio`, due to the silent loading of previous workspaces and packages of the latter.

Test set-up by running `system('gcc -v')` in a `R` session to obtain:

```
COLLECT_GCC=F:\Rtools\MINGW-~1\X64-48~1.1-P\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=f:/rtools/mingw-~1/x64-48~1.1-p/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
[Edited Config info]
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 (rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
```

To confirm *a selection of* compiler bugs present with `gcc 4.6.3 to 4.8.0` are no more, as well as test some new `C++11` features available with `gcc 4.8.*`, in a `R` session running `Rcpp::sourceCpp` on the following code, saved as `.cpp` file, should generate no compiler warnings or errors (whereas this will totally fail using `gcc 4.6.3`):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]


template<typename T>
struct Wrap 
{
    int test2(int depth)
    {
        m_test++;
        std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
        return depth == 0? 1 : std::accumulate(
             v.begin(), v.end(), int(0), [=](int sub, int const&) {
             return sub + test2(depth - 1);
             });   
    }

    int m_test = 0;
};


  struct X
{
  template <class T> static void bar() {}

  template <class T> void foo(T p) 
  {
    [&] { bar<T>(); };
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double inheriting(int in_){

struct A { 
  A(int u){
    hello = u*u/2.0;
  }; 
double hello;
};

struct B: A { using A::A; };

  B b(in_);
  return(b.hello);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_lambda(int in_)
{
  X x;
  x.foo(in_);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
int test_bug_4_7_2(int in_){

Wrap<int> w;
return w.test2(in_);
}
```

Comment: Can you forward this information to R-Core and ask them to update the Rtools distribution with this updated compiler? ;)

Comment: I think R Core would want a version that builds R with all tests passing.  They care much more about C than C++ though...

Answer (score 2):

Here I describe how we can use **GCC v8.1.0** with Rtools to compile source packages in R.

This is tested on Windows 10 64 bit Home edition with [R v3.5.0](https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.5.0.tar.gz) and [Rtools35](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe).

1. Install [R](https://www.r-project.org/)
2. Install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/Rtools35.exe). The default installation location will be `C:\Rtools`. You will see following subfolders inside `Rtools`:

[image]

3. Set the path so that `Rtools` is in path by editing environment variable as below:

[image]

4. Delete whatever is present inside `mingw_64` subfolder inside `Rtools`.
5. Now go to download gcc from [this MinGW distro](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html). Download [mingw-16.0-without-git.exe](https://nuwen.net/files/mingw/mingw-16.0-without-git.exe).

[image]

Install in its default location. Note that by default, it will get installed in `MinGW\` folder. Copy/Cut whatever is **inside** this `MinGW\` folder.

6. Go to `mingw_64` **subfolder** inside `Rtools` and paste whatever been copied/cut in step 5. After pasting you will see this  inside `mingw_64` sub-folder:

[image]

6. Test your setup to compile C/C++ code in R package `rdatatable` with following lines in `R` console:

   ```
   remove.packages("data.table")
   install.packages("data.table", type = "source",
   repos = "http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")
   ```

If successful, you will find something like this:

[image]

It compiles `Rcpp` from source too !

It can compile all `R packages` with compiled code, except those with dependencies on external libraries.