# Problems with Rcpp, C++11, vectors and Windows

Tags: c++, windows, r, c++11, rcpp

I try to use Rcpp with C++11 on 64bit Windows. I followed https://stackoverflow.com/a/25456836 and used gcc 4.8.1 with R 3.1.1 and Rcpp 0.11.2.

With the C++ file `simpleProd.cpp`

```cpp
#include <vector>

// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]
int simpleProd(std::vector<int> vec) {

  vec.push_back(5);

  int prod = 1;
  for (int &x : vec) {       // loop over all values of vec
    prod *= x;              // access each elem., comp. product
  }  
  return prod;
}
```

I tried in R

```r
library("Rcpp")
Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++11")
unlink("mypkg", recursive = TRUE)
Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypkg", cpp_files = "simpleProd.cpp", 
                      example_code = FALSE)
install.packages("mypkg", repos = NULL, type = "source", 
                 INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")
library(mypkg)
```

With no problems, but if I run

```r
simpleProd(1:5)
```

the result is

```r
Error in .Call("mypkg_simpleProd", PACKAGE = "mypkg", vec) : 
  "mypkg_simpleProd" not available for .Call() for package "mypkg"
```

If I just use

```r
  sourceCpp("simpleProd.cpp")
  simpleProd(1:5)
```

there is no problem. If `vec.push_back(5);` is removed or no C++11 is used there is no problem. On Linux and Mac there is no problem and finally on 32bit Windows (with the corresponding toolchain) there is no problem.

Any idea? Thank you!

Edit: To clarify: The problem only occurs in the special case with:

**64bit Windows + Rcpp + Package + C++11 + vector operation**.

If I change one of these, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to run

```
  compileAttributes("mypkg")          # or setwd() into the directory first
```

to have the Attributes generated.

The skeleton packages does that.  If you work in RStudio it is also semi-automatic.

*Edit* Or to be more explicit, when you use the `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` function with a supplied file we may not be running `compileAttributes()` for you.  Which is a bug -- I'll look into that.  But you can fix it by running the function by hand.

*Edit 2:* I may have been wrong about the need for `compileAttributes()`. Your example works for me (using current GitHub sources of Rcpp).  However, I did have to enable C++11 compilation -- which I did the via user-wide `CXXFLAGS` in `~/.R/Makevars`.  The skeleton code does not infer the need for this from the plugin use in the supplied file.  You could also edit `DESCRIPTION` or `src/Makevars` by hand and add it manually.

*Edit 3:* There is no issue.  On Windows, you i) have to downgrade the C++11 compiler option as the compiler is older (which is not something we have control over), and ii) I also removed your constraint of excluding multi-arch.  Then it all works, see below.  This is a standard Windows 7 box running the current R and current packages.

```
R> setwd("C:/TEMP")
R> library(Rcpp)
R> Sys.setenv("PKG_CPPFLAGS"="-std=c++0x")
R> Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypkg", cpp_files = "simpleProd.cpp", example_code = FALSE)
Creating directories ...
Creating DESCRIPTION ...
Creating NAMESPACE ...
Creating Read-and-delete-me ...
Saving functions and data ...
Making help files ...
Done.
Further steps are described in './mypkg/Read-and-delete-me'.

Adding Rcpp settings
 >> added Imports: Rcpp
 >> added LinkingTo: Rcpp
 >> added useDynLib directive to NAMESPACE
 >> added importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp) directive to NAMESPACE
 >> copied simpleProd.cpp to src directory
R> install.packages("mypkg", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘c:/opt/R-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'mypkg' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
g++ -m32 -I"C:/opt/R-CURR~1/include" -DNDEBUG -std=c++0x   -I"c:/opt/R-library/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -m32 -I"C:/opt/R-CURR~1/include" -DNDEBUG -std=c++0x   -I"c:/opt/R-library/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c simpleProd.cpp -o simpleProd.o
g++ -m32 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o mypkg.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o simpleProd.o -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/i386 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/opt/R-CURR~1/bin/i386 -lR
installing to c:/opt/R-library/mypkg/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
g++ -m64 -I"C:/opt/R-CURR~1/include" -DNDEBUG -std=c++0x   -I"c:/opt/R-library/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -m64 -I"C:/opt/R-CURR~1/include" -DNDEBUG -std=c++0x   -I"c:/opt/R-library/Rcpp/include" -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c simpleProd.cpp -o simpleProd.o
g++ -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o mypkg.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o simpleProd.o -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/opt/R-CURR~1/bin/x64 -lR
installing to c:/opt/R-library/mypkg/libs/x64
** R
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
Warning: C:/TEMP/mypkg/man/mypkg-package.Rd:30: All text must be in a section
Warning: C:/TEMP/mypkg/man/mypkg-package.Rd:31: All text must be in a section
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (mypkg)
R> library(mypkg)
R> simpleProd(1:5)
[1] 600
R>
```

Comment: Thank you Dirk. Unfortunately it's still not working. I originally used `Makevars` and `Makevars.win`, and just replaced it by `Sys.setenv("PKG_CXXFLAGS"="-std=c++11")` to simplify the example.

Please note that the only case where the problem occurs is:

`64bit Windows + Rcpp + Package + C++11 + vector operation`.

Comment: Let's keep this apart, shall we?  64-bit Windows and vector operations have nothing to do with this.  You "simply" opted to use C++11 standards, which (as an optional feature) are not automatically recognized by `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` -- no more, no less.  If there is another issue that I am missing please report it on the list with a reproducible example.

Comment: C++11 is not the problem, the flag is set. We can't keep this apart because it is the problem. The reproducible example is in the question, it works on Linux, Mac and Win32, but not on Win64.

Comment: And C++11 can easily gotten rid of here by rewriting the loop as standard C / C++-1998 loop.  Now win64 and win32 use the same (dated) gcc binary. Why would win64 be different?  And again, the rcpp-devel is a better forum for extended discussion as you will get more visibility.

Comment: Yes, the above example could be rewritten without C++11. Unfortunately, for my real package this is not the case. Thank you again, I will post this on rcpp-revel.

Comment: See my last edit. I cannot replicate your issue in a fresh session, with your unaltered `simpleProd.cpp`.